# Fitnesse How to acces _root.wiki content in Java

Tags: java, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

Pretty new to Fitnesse I am trying to figure out how to acces the _root.wiki (where we have all our database properties set) from my java code fixture extended with SlimFixture.

What I tried so far:

- Tried to set a symbol in the fixture.wiki, but I did not work and I think it is meant to be setted in Java and used in de Wiki. Right?
- Tried to !define variables in Fixture.wiki, but the Fixture does not see them when debugging in Java

What I think might work, but do not want for a reason;

- Use the fixture parameters to add the properties. However, I am aiming to use these parameters for creating different objects in the database and with these properties added the parameter list groes.....

My workaround idea:

- Read the wiki file via its path and filter out the properties I need. Not very nice.

Maybe I have it all wrong, but I hope you guys might tell me a way use wiki data in my java fixture code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is an easy way to get the contents of a .wiki page in your fixture code (at least there is not supposed to be one ;-)).

Your approach of passing parameters to your fixtures is what I would recommend. But I completely understand that passing many properties in is not very nice. Especially maintaining a large list when the same list is used in many tests in no good.

What I would recommend that you create a (container) variable, some sort of map/hash, that you first fill with all the properties you need, and then pass that to your fixtures. In that way you only have to pass a single variable to tests and adding/removing properties does not affect how you call your fixtures. The variable is a slim variable which can be modified at runtime.

In [my fixtures project](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures) I created a [MapFixture](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/hsac/fitnesse/fixture/slim/MapFixture.java) and [MapOfMapsFixture](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/hsac/fitnesse/fixture/slim/MapOfMapsFixture.java) that allow you, besides checking the contents of a map, to manipulate the context of a map to define such a variable. What properties to put into it can then be defined in a (Suite)SetUp or by scenarios. The project also contains sample pages showing usage of [MapFixture](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/master/wiki/FitNesseRoot/HsacExamples/SlimTests/UtilityFixtures/MapFixtureTest.wiki) of [MapOfMapsFixture](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/master/wiki/FitNesseRoot/HsacExamples/SlimTests/UtilityFixtures/MapOfMapsFixture.wiki).

For example in a SetUp page:

```
|script     |map fixture                |
|set value  |user   |for       |username|
|set value  |secret |for       |password|
|$dbProps=  |copy map                   |
```

And then in the test page itself:

```
|script |database test |
|connect using|$dbProps|
```